# Fetch order data based on order item with particular seller in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want order data with order item of particular seller in django. But when i fetch with code in view.py it returns data of all the sellers.
I don't know why? Please tell me what to do.

Here is my models:

**Order Model:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, default='')
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    @property
    def order_items(self):
        return self.orderitem_set.all()
```

**Order Item:**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, to_field='order_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entrepreneur = models.ForeignKey(Entrepreneur, to_field='entrepreneur_id', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True,
                                     null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, default='New')
```

And here is my **views.py**:

```
def list_order_by_status_entrepreneur_view(request):
    order = Order.objects.distinct().filter(orderitem__entrepreneur_id=request.data['entrepreneur_id'],
                                            orderitem__status=request.data['status'])
    serializer = ListOrderSerializer(order, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class ListOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
order_items = ListOrderItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Order
    exclude = ('id',)

class ListOrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
entrepreneur = EntrepreneurSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = OrderItem
    exclude = ('id',)
```

Comment: There is no error, but the order i get from this function is from all the sellers and i want particular seller which i mentioned here as entrepreneur id

Comment: btw, can you post the serializer?

Comment: when you say `it returns data of all the sellers` you mean `orders from all sellers` or `the right orders but also contains OrderItems from other sellers` ?

Comment: yes right orders are there, but also contains orders from other seller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230791/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-dani-herrera).

Comment: Issue not resolved yet. Please tell me what to do.